# android camera not saving picture

Tags: android, camera, storage

the following is my code to take a picture

```
            File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            String name = imageFileName;
            File file = new File(path, name);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), file.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST); 


}

static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
    this.imageView = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.mImageView);
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
        imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
    }  

    }
```

This works fine takes the photo and puts a thumbnail in the imageview

problem is it saves the picture in the DCIM card on the SD Card when it should save it in the pictures folder with the filename "Imagefilename"

the toast i have put in reports the full path as

storage/emulated/0/Pictures/filename.jpg but the picture is not saved there

i have set read write permissions in the manifest

any ideas where im going wrong

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need this:

```
cameraIntent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,outputFileUri );
```

prior to calling startActivityForResult.. so copying your code  above:

```
        File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        String name = imageFileName;
        File file = new File(path, name);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), file.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 

        cameraIntent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,outputFileUri );// add this

        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

Comment: isnt that the same as  Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);  which i already have before start activity for result?

Comment: i tried putting that instead and it says cameraintent cannot be resolved